# Use link in lightbox gallery caption

Tags: amp-html

I'm using amp-lightbox gallery to show a gallery for some related images. Images are of products, so there is a product page for each image.

I would also like users to be able to navigate to product pages through lightbox.

Is this possible?

Using `a` tag in `figcaption` does not work, seems like only text content is shown in lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported by AMP (but sounds like a great feature to have). Can you please file a feature request [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Type%3A%20Feature%20Request&template=feature_request.md&title=)?